# Firing events at specific times into a video played by MPMoviePlayerController (for Custom Captions on Movie)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, closed-captions

I'm considering implementing an SRT File parser for overlaying videos over an MPMoviePlayerController class. Can anyone think of a reliable way to fire off events at very specific times while a movie's playing?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not as familiar with iOS as I am with AppKit, but doesn't look like there's a direct equivalent of AppKit's NSTimer class.

I suppose you could always use CoreFoundation's CFTimer (found in CFRunLoop.h), or NSObject's: `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay`

For example:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateSubtitle:) withObject:nextSubtitle afterDelay:0.5];
```

If the user fast-forwards, or rewinds or something you'd want to call the following to cancel any scheduled events from happening:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about this approach. However since this works with the runloop. I wonder about its precision.

Comment: NSTimer is present.  It's in Foundation, not AppKit.

Comment: @Ken: Wow, duh. Thanks. For whatever reason, I was thinking that NSTimer had to be in AppKit because it relied on the run loop, which I mis-remembered (or reasoned) as being defined in AppKit. Indeed both NSRunLoop and NSTimer are defined in Foundation.