# Delaying a function call on OS X

Tags: c++, macos

I've seen there is a sleep method in the Win32 API and also a timer class to delay function calls.

Is there something similar that I can use on Mac OS?

I want a simple solution to create some sort of `setTimeout` function found in JavaScript and AS3.

Comment: I'm tempted to -1 this for failure to simply open terminal and type `apropos sleep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFTimer` actually exists in Core Foundation, which *is* C++ & C compatible.

It's not very well documented at all, from what I can tell.  [Here is a related question that mentions it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131137/firing-events-at-specific-times-into-a-video-played-by-mpmovieplayercontroller).

On a higher level, there's also the standard C call of [`sleep` (I've linked the man page for you here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html), and if you want to do this as a `setTimeout` type of function you could figure out a way to do `sleep` from a separate thread and then when it finishes (without being killed), consider things "timed out".

Answer (score 4):

You may do it using 2 methods:

1) Use `NSObject`'s `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

2) Use Grand Central Dispatch, like this:

```
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    your code here
});
```

Or, for shorter syntax, you may add the following functions somewhere to your project:

```
void Dispatch_AfterDelay(dispatch_queue_t queue, NSTimeInterval afterInterval, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, afterInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(delay, queue, block);
}

void Dispatch_AfterDelay_ToMainThread(NSTimeInterval afterInterval, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    Dispatch_AfterDelay(dispatch_get_main_queue(), afterInterval, block);
}
```

And then you just call:

```
Dispatch_AfterDelay_ToMainThread(5.0, ^{
    your code
});
```

Comment: NSTimeInterval? That is part of Cocoa... I need C++ not objective C.

Comment: If we are not inside main queue, how can we get back to the thread before?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a C function (or a block) to wrap your C++ code, then you can use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079).

Look at `dispatch_after_f` for a delayed call of a function or `dispatch_after` for its block based equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Unix calls like [sleep()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/) and [poll()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/poll/).